# T-SQL dynamic linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I have two separated enviroments (Test and Production). Each environment has two servers (istN and istG).

**And their linked servers:**

- Test (linked server from istG to istN): test01\istN. 
  If used in a query is:

  `SELECT * FROM [test01\istn].MyDatabase.dbo.Table01`
- Production (linked server from istG to istN) production01\istn
  If used in a query is:

  `SELECT * FROM [production01\istn].MyDatabase.dbo.table01`

We use a release-system that deploy the same SQL script in each enviroment (test and production) regardless of the environment:

so how is possibile to write only one script that can be used in the enviroments?
is there a method to get a dynamic linked server?
like this:

`SELECT * FROM [@variable].MyDatabase.dbo.table01`

Thanks.

Comment: You could name linked servers _regardless of the environment_.

Comment: can't do it. i'm not the owner of the whole infrastructure (it's a bank). So i have to stay under their rules.

Comment: then your way is a dynamic sql or limitedly applicable method of `view` with union and servername as a column

Comment: or try to alter your deployment tool/script to avoid direct linking to any server in random places of your code. Put somewhere `use ...` or substitution meta-code like `##replace_me_with_proper_server_name_when_rebuilding_deployment_package##`

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below Query. Its working fine in SQL Server 2012.

```
DECLARE @LinkedServer VARCHAR(100)
SET @LinkedServer ='production01\istn'
EXEC('SELECT * FROM ['+@LinkedServer+'].MyDatabase.dbo.table01')
```

Please use the below is you need to get the server name during execution:

```
DECLARE @LinkedServer VARCHAR(100)
SET @LinkedServer =(SELECT @@SERVERNAME)
EXEC('SELECT * FROM ['+@LinkedServer+'].MyDatabase.dbo.table01')
```

Comment: Ok, now it works. But there is another problem: if i need to build a stored procedure with an  update statement? and i update the the table on the other server.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand your requirement. Can you explain?

Comment: I need to build a stored procedure (which will be released in the same automatic release structure). In the SP i need to write an update statement. Is possibile to use the same instruction you gave? the table which is going to be updated is found on the other server (the "linked" one)

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
DECLARE @linkedServer VARCHAR(50) = ''

EXEC ('select * from openquery(' + @linkedServer + ', ''SELECT * FROM MyDatabase.dbo.Table01''')
```